# How to connect to a print driver in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, driver, converters

I have an task of converting bunch of formats like `.pdf, .doc, .jpg, .xls, .txt, .bmp` file types into `.png` format. I found a print driver that does that.

But how do I connect to that printer driver in .net? This will a server side component. I need to print documents into a folder using this print driver.

I am wondering how that can be done.

Thanks

Comment: I believe your question is unclear as to the intended purpose. Why don't you provide a link to the driver you are talking about and elaborate on your question in a little more detail? Step by step, what is it you are hoping to accomplish? I ask for clarification, as a printer driver in and of itself has nothing to do with converting the document/file formats you list to a rendered .PNG version of them.

Comment: @dmarietta: actually, there are several print drivers that render to file instead of to PCL or Postscript.

Comment: I was looking at http://code-industry.net/imageprinterpro.php and 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/imageprinter/support

1). User will upload files with file extensions specified above
2). My server would have the printer driver installed. 
3). My web service will receive xml with required info and location of the files on the server.
4). Application will use the printer driver, just like other .net applications will use a real printer drivers to print documents to a certain location on the server. 
5). Then the application will get those files and Save them to a database.

Comment: I know a to pdf conversion would be much eaiser and there are a lot more libraries available, but to .png is requirement that I was specified. If you a better way to do this, please let me know. 

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your updated comments, it sounds as if you are looking to convert a variety of images and document types to a single common image type. The process of taking one of the several possible source formats you mention and convert it to a bitmapped format such as .PNG is referred to as RENDERING or RASTERIZING. You want to take one of the input formats, render it to a bitmap representation, then write it to a file in .PNG format. While it certainly might be possible to do this using a print driver, to do so, you would typically be relying on an installed application that would allow you to pass the source document to it for printing to the driver. For this to work, each of the source file types you want to be able to handle this way needs to have an application installed which can take actions from the shell and do what you request. So for example if you want to do this with a .DOC file, you need Microsoft Word installed as it does properly respond to the PRINT shell command. However, the limitation with the shell based method is that it is always going to print to the DEFAULT system printer. So your driver would need to be setup as the default printer for the machine you are going to run your process on. Therefore you would need to see if each of the source types you want to be able to handle have an installed or installable application which will allow you to print them using the shell and the PRINT action verb.

Reference URLs:

[Windows Shell Verbs and File Associations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The problem with this technique is not all applications respond to the PRINT verb correctly or at all. This usually works with all the major Microsoft applications, but you should test any other document types you want to support before going much further with this technique.

This also raises other questions that this doesn't even begin to address such as what to do about multiple page formats. You listed a few image types that are straight-forward and can be converted to PNG files pretty directly. But how do you want to render a multiple page Word document files into PNG format? Do you intend for only one very large PNG with all the pages one after another? Or do you intend for one PNG file per corresponding source document page? The print driver method might not give you very much control over that.

Depending on some of these details and just how much control and reliability you need in the process, you might want to consider a completely different route to your process. Maybe you should consider using tools/libraries that can read the source file formats you want to support and render them directly, after which you can save into your PNG files. One library I have used in the past that would seem to fit and allow you a high degree of control over the conversion (rendering/rasterization) process is LeadTools. It is a fairly pricey product, but my experience with it has been that it does support a wide variety of formats reliably.

[LeadTools PDF and Document Readers SDK](http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/pdf/pdf-reader.htm?linkid=top)

There may be some other open source tools available that you could pull together to support this type of functionality, but I'm not familiar with any to point you to anything specific. But hopefully this helps give you some information to look at putting together a process that might be more reliable and give you greater control than trying to coerce a printer driver to do something you might not quite be able to make work reliably.

Answer (score 1):

Server-side component implies something that doesn't have a human sitting at it (at least, not the human that is trying to use that printer).  If this is the case then a print driver will not work - Print drivers that write their output to disk instead of a device always, in my experience, ask the user to select a place to save the file (present a Save As dialog).

Comment: I was thinking if is a print driver, I would have it save to a default location on the server. Just like how a .net component needs to use the printer driver to print an actual documents to a real printer. I would call the virtual driver to print the documents I specify from the .net web service. I am not even sure if this is possible, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: SPeaking of print drivers specifically - there is no api to specify a save location other than via the UI.  What you want is a conversion library.

Comment: I am assuming I can specify the location, when I install the driver on the server. But I am not too sure, I have looked at libraries, Aspose is the only one remotely comes close to that.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a little bit on what Boo mentioned :

Depending on the printer driver you are using, you may be able to tell it where to save your file.

The problem is by using a printer, how it normally works is that you can print from any application to a .png file. But the application itself has to know how to open and render (not talk to the printer) the content of the original file.

To continue down this path, you have to make sure your server component knows how to read and render content of each file type (.jpg, .pdf, .doc, etc.).

Assuming your server component knows how to render the content, the next step from here is to use the .NET Printing namespace to print your content to the .png printer.

For more details go to : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188767.aspx

Comment: Would my component be able to find the virtual print driver in the driver list somewhere?